# Stop AVAudioPlayer music when the app goes to background

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit, avaudioplayer

I'm developing a little game and I'm using AVAudioPlayer in order to play the game's background music. The problem is that if the user exits the app without closing it in the app drawer (so it is in the background) the music will not stop. How can I change this? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In the ViewController where you handle your AVAudioPlayer add this in your viewDidLoad

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appWillResignActive:) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appWillTerminate:) name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:nil];
```

Then you add those 2 methods :

```
-(void) appWillResignActive:(NSNotification*)note{
    NSLog(@"App is going to the background");
    // This is where you stop the music 
}
-(void) appWillTerminate:(NSNotification*)note{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:nil];

    NSLog(@"App will terminate");
}
```

Comment: "resign active" is not the same as entering the background. Use `UIApplicationDidEnterBackground` instead of `UIApplicationWillResignActive` to be notified when the app enters the background.

Comment: And there's no point in removing the observers in the "app will terminate" notification. The app is terminating. Such cleanup is pointless at that stage.

Comment: True but I like the symmetry, and that little exercise ensure I never forget to remove Notifications.

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer here is that you want to configure the AVAudioSession to use the category AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient.

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient error:nil];
```

This before you activate the session of course.